# Algolia PHP SDK query returns "host unreachable"

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I am using the Laravel Scout Algolia driver. I am up and running with the instant search using autocomplete.jquery.js on the front end. But on backend when I query in my controller `Class::search($query)->get()` it runs into a timeout.

```
Hosts unreachable: Resolving timed out after 1000 milliseconds,Resolving timed out after 1000 milliseconds,Operation timed out after 3037 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received,Resolving timed out after 3000 milliseconds
```

I have tried increasing timeout as well. Please help.

Comment: Where are you trying to run your code - locally or in a production environment? Is your host connected to the internet? Did you try to ping one of the algolia servers manually?

Comment: i am running it locally. i havn't tried to ping algolia servers. but when i try my live search module, that works fine

Comment: Then please try pinging / name resolving the algolia servers, because it reads like you had normal connection issues that are not directly related to the algolia service. Are you using homestead?

Comment: no i am using laravel valet. where can i find ip addresses of algolia servers

Comment: Can you try to connect to `APP_ID-dsn.algolia.net` ?